# Laravel - Multiple Language Sources

Tags: php, laravel, multilingual

Is there any way to have multiple language sources in Laravel without having them namespaced?

I want to be able to add a language “plugin” which will be stored in, for instance, `plugins/SpanishLanguagePlugin/lang/es` or `plugins/GermanLanguagePlugin/lang/de`.

I currently do the following: `\App::setLocale(config('app.locale'));`

`config('app.locale')` can only be changed by the Administrator via the UI which is then updated for all users. But, initially, only the English language is installed as a plugin. The site administrator then has the option to download the Spanish/German languages (more will be added in the future -- hence why we're adding them as plugins).

Answer (score 0):

I have created a package called **Laravel PolyTranslate** that can help you with that.

You can find it here https://github.com/deployteam/laravel-polytranslate

It will allow you to add multiple paths without a namespace, and multiple paths for a single namespace.